# Face Book 3.0 in Android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have created an application that needs to post status automatically to facebook wall.

I have successfully enabled login/logout session using SDK 3.0. I am trying out posting status on my wall by pressing a button.

I tried the following:

[Facebook Publish to feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/)

I was not able to publish it. After clicking post to wall button (I have created) - I get a new screen with a progress bar, after few seconds - it gets back to Main screen. nothing updated on my wall.

**UPDATE**

If I disable:

```
    if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
        pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
        return;
    }
```

this part of the code. I can post the message. If I do it. this works only in my phone not on different phones. How do I fix this up?

**Update -2:**

After I comment return part - I get an force close but I do get the permission dialog box.

here is error and it is point to:

JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();

Here is the error:
06-05 12:50:43.932: E/AndroidRuntime(21933): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 12:50:43.932: E/AndroidRuntime(21933): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 12:50:43.932: E/AndroidRuntime(21933):    at com.test.fbtest.Sessionvalid$1.onCompleted(Sessionvalid.java:216)
06-05 12:50:43.932: E/AndroidRuntime(21933):    at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1240)
06-05 12:50:43.932: E/AndroidRuntime(21933):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-05 12:50:43.932: E/AndroidRuntime(21933):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-05 12:50:43.932: E/AndroidRuntime(21933):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-05 12:50:43.932: E/AndroidRuntime(21933):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-05 12:50:43.932: E/AndroidRuntime(21933):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 12:50:43.932: E/AndroidRuntime(21933):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-05 12:50:43.932: E/AndroidRuntime(21933):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-05 12:50:43.932: E/AndroidRuntime(21933):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-05 12:50:43.932: E/AndroidRuntime(21933):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Not really sure why should I get an error there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the return statement.it works for me.

```
if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
        pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
       'remove return statement=>' return;
    }
```

Working sample,

```
private void publishStory()
        {


List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

            if (session != null)
                {

                    // Check for publish permissions
                    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
                    if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions))
                        {
                            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                        }

                    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
                    postParams.putString("name", "Sample google for for Android");
                    postParams.putString("caption", "world of data");
                    postParams.putString("description","Various religios music, chants, mantras, christian songs, islamic music, quran and more.");
                    postParams.putString("link", "http://www.google.com/");
                    postParams.putString("picture", "http://www.userlogos.org/files/logos/veinedstorm/raaga.png");

                    Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback()
                        {
                            public void onCompleted(Response response)
                                {
                                    JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                                    String postId = null;
                                    try
                                        {
                                            postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                                        }
                                    catch (JSONException e)
                                        {
                                            Log.i("JSON", "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                                        }
                                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                                    Log.e("post response",response.toString());
                                    if (error != null)
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(checkAndPostActivity.this, error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                    .show();
                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(checkAndPostActivity.this, postId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                }
                        };

                    Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

                    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
                    task.execute();
                }

        }



private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset)
        {
            for (String string : subset)
                {
                    if (!superset.contains(string))
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Didn't work. I get force close. :( - with null pointer exception..Any idea on what the PERMISSIONS code do?

Comment: permissions allow us to read and write(read and post) .when we create facebook session without any permission then by default it users the "Read permission".But to post on facebook we have to give "Write permission" explicitly.here issubset() function check the write permissions

Comment: Got it.. So the return part has to be enable orelse it will not work right?

Comment: in my code ,i have removed the return statement,and it just works fine for me! and one more very important thing "make sure that your session is in "OPENED" state before posting".

Comment: Yep. I have put this inside: if (session.isOpened())
  {

Comment: Also I have just put the whole code of publishStory and private boolean isSubsetOf. Am I missing anythign else?

Comment: I used your sample code. I get an error. updated on my main questions. Couldn't figure why I should get an error there?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31232/discussion-between-dd619-and-thedevman)